# mysql where type int

Tags: mysql, casting, where-clause

my table 'users' have a following schema

### | id | name | class|

| 0 | John | Primary |
| 1 | Mary | Primary |

I tried this query:

```
select * from users where id = 'a'
```

The mysql return all rows from table.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If `id` is of type Integer, you have to type it without quotation marks. For example:

```
select * from users where id = 0;
```

should return:

```
| 0 | John | Primary
```

However, the `'a'` in your example is not an Integer, so I am not 100 percent sure where this comes from and if I understood you correctly.